# Downloading flash movies from any source!

Tags: video, download

i was wondering if its possible? There are many extensions to firefox which help you to download vides from e.g; youtube etc but there are many websites which offer video training tutorials etc e.g; lynda and vtc. How you can download videos from them?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well i have found that realplayer browser plugin is best for this.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any general method. Youtube keeps changing its model to prevent downloads, and other site probably do the same. Flash videos are often more easily grabbed under linux : the flv file is simply downloaded to /tmp.

Edit 2014: this was true using Flash player 9 (and older). Unfortunately, since Flash Player 10 the video file is still created in /tmp, but immediately removed. It's therefore invisible and tricky to copy; you may want to try searching for open but deleted files using `lsof` and restore it from `/proc` as [described here](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/58142).

Comment: I like that. I will check next time.

Answer (score 1):

[Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) is great for that sort of thing, you can pretty much look at every request the browser is making including the FLV. I use this to download videos from any site and it works a charm each time.

Comment: Hmm thanks, let me check if it will work with site which i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The DownloadHelper plugin lets you do that.

Comment: Except when it doesn't.  DownloadHelper only works when the video is streamed over http--rtsp streaming is invisible to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I used to use some app called FLVDownloader, but you can also do it with MS VPC 2007, and IE8 running an XP client. For some reason on Vista and Win 7 it doesn't seem to work. Just view the YouTube movie then grab it from temporary internet files. Easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working under Windows, [Orbit Downloader](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/) is darn effective. Free of charge (ad supported, it looks like.)